# Element not orthogonal to any other non zero element

Tags: inner-products

Consider an inner product space. Does there(always) exist a non zero element which is not orthogonal to any other non zero element? In other way, can I always find a non zero element which is orthogonal to a given non zero element?

For example, in the Cartesian plane to any non zero vector one can consider the vector perpendicular to it, which is orthogonal. But is it true for any general inner product space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the inner product is of dimension $1$ or $0$, then yes. The zero vector in a $0$-dimensional space will be orthogonal only to the $0$ vector (trivially). In a $1$-dimensional space, we can form a basis out of any non-zero vector $v$, and we have, for any scalar $a$,
$$\langle av, v \rangle = a \langle v, v \rangle \neq 0 \text{ if }a \neq 0.$$
Otherwise, no, there is no such vector. In an inner product space of dimension greater than $1$ (possibly infinite), we may find two linearly independent vectors $v$ and $w$. Consider,
$$u = w - \frac{\langle w, v \rangle}{\langle v, v \rangle} v.$$
Then
$$\langle u, v \rangle = \left\langle w - \frac{\langle w, v \rangle}{\langle v, v \rangle} v, v \right\rangle = \langle w, v \rangle - \frac{\langle w, v \rangle}{\langle v, v \rangle} \langle v, v\rangle = 0.$$
If it were the case that $v$ were only orthogonal with the $0$ vector, then we would have to have
$$w - \frac{\langle w, v \rangle}{\langle v, v \rangle} v = 0,$$
which would contradict the linear independence of $v$ and $w$.

Comment: This is Gram-Schmidt orthogonalisation right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

No, not in general. Take $\mathbb R$ with the inner product $\langle x,y\rangle=xy$. But in a space with dimension greater than $1$, it is true.

Comment: I should have asked clearly, space in my mind is having dimension more than 2 actually. Can you explain how is it true? (Can you post it in answer?)

Comment: Why? Another poster has already provided an answer to that question.